# Android emulator does not start webcam for camera

Tags: camera, android-emulator, webcam, android-virtual-device

I can't use my laptop webcam as emulators camera. When I launch the camera from emulator, it show force closed. Console shows:

> emulator: ERROR: _camera_client_query_start: Cannot start camera 'AndroidEmulatorVC0' for NV21[640x480]: No error

I assigned 200mb for sd card in emulator
and configured back camera to webcam0, front camera to none.

And I checked my webcam with other windows applications (e.g. Skype). No issue in webcam driver.

I want to take picture from my app in emulator - what should I do?